# Handle multiple JavaFX application launches within a loop

Tags: javafx, controller, jakarta-mail, stage, actionevent

My code currently reads my Gmail inbox via IMAP (imaps) and javamail, and once it finds an email with zip/xap attachment, it displays a stage (window) asking whether to download the file, yes or no.

I want the stage to close once I make a selection, and then return to the place within the loop from which the call came. My problem arises because you cannot launch an application more than once, so I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320014/how-to-call-launch-more-than-once-in-java) that I should write `Platform.setImplicitExit(false);` in the `start` method, and then use `primartyStage.hide()` (?) and then something like `Platform.runLater(() -> primaryStage.show());` when I need to display the stage again later.

The problem occuring now is that the flow of command begins in Mail.java's `doit()` method which loops through my inbox, and `launch(args)` occurs within a `for loop` within the method. This means `launch(args)` then calls `start` to set the scene, and show the stage. Since there is a `Controller.java` and `fxml` associated, the Controller class has an event handler for the stage's buttons which "intercept" the flow once `start` has shown the stage. Therefore when I click Yes or No it hides the stage but then just **hangs there.** As if it can't return to the start method to continue the loop from where launch(args) occurred. How do I properly hide/show the stage whenever necessary, allowing the loop to continue whether yes or no was clicked.

Here is the code for Mail.java and Controller.java. Thanks a lot!

**Mail.java**

```
 [Other variables set here]
    public static int launchCount = 0;@FXML public Text subjectHolder;

    public static ReceiveMailImap obj = new ReceiveMailImap();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,        MessagingException {
        ReceiveMailImap.doit();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("prompts.fxml"));
        root = loader.load();
        controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setPrimaryStage(primaryStage);
        scene = new Scene(root, 450, 250);
        controller.setPrimaryScene(scene);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("styleMain.css");
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Download this file?");
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void doit() throws MessagingException, IOException {
        Folder inbox = null;
        Store store = null;

        try {
            Properties props = System.getProperties();
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            store = session.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "myAccount@gmail.com", "Password");
            inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
            Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();
            FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
            fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
            fp.add(UIDFolder.FetchProfileItem.FLAGS);
            fp.add(UIDFolder.FetchProfileItem.CONTENT_INFO);
            fp.add("X-mailer");

            inbox.fetch(messages, fp);
            int doc = 0;
            int maxDocs = 400;
            for (int i = messages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                Message message = messages[i];
                if (doc < maxDocs) {
                    doc++;
                    message.getSubject();

                    if (!hasAttachments(message)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    String from = "Sender Unknown";
                    if (message.getReplyTo().length >= 1) {
                        from = message.getReplyTo()[0].toString();
                    } else if (message.getFrom().length >= 1) {
                        from = message.getFrom()[0].toString();
                    }
                    subject = message.getSubject();
                    if (from.contains("myAccount@gmail.com")) {
                        saveAttachment(message.getContent());
                        message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true);
                    }
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (inbox != null) {
                inbox.close(true);
            }
            if (store != null) {
                store.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean hasAttachments(Message msg) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        if (msg.isMimeType("multipart/mixed")) {
            Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
            if (mp.getCount() > 1) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void saveAttachment(Object content)
    throws IOException, MessagingException {
        out = null; in = null;
        try {
            if (content instanceof Multipart) {
                Multipart multi = ((Multipart) content);
                parts = multi.getCount();
                for (int j = 0; j < parts; ++j) {
                    part = (MimeBodyPart) multi.getBodyPart(j);
                    if (part.getContent() instanceof Multipart) {
                        // part-within-a-part, do some recursion...
                        saveAttachment(part.getContent());
                    } else {
                        int allow = 0;
                        if (part.isMimeType("application/x-silverlight-app")) {
                            extension = "xap";
                            allow = 1;
                        } else {
                            extension = "zip";
                            allow = 1;
                        }
                        if (allow == 1) {
                            if (launchCount == 0) {
                                launch(args);
                                launchCount++;
                            } else {
                                Platform.runLater(() -> primaryStage.show());
                            }
                        } else {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if ( in != null) { in .close();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static File createFolder(String subject) {
        JFileChooser fr = new JFileChooser();
        FileSystemView myDocs = fr.getFileSystemView();
        String myDocuments = myDocs.getDefaultDirectory().toString();
        dir = new File(myDocuments + "\\" + subject);
        savePathNoExtension = dir.toString();
        dir.mkdir();
        System.out.println("Just created: " + dir);
        return dir;
    }

}
```

**Controller.java**

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Text subjectHolder;
    public Button yesButton, noButton;
    public ReceiveMailImap subject;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        subject= new ReceiveMailImap();
        subjectHolder.setText(subject.returnSubject());
    }
    public Stage primaryStage;
    public Scene scene;

    @FXML
    ComboBox<String> fieldCombo;

    public void setPrimaryStage(Stage stage) {
        this.primaryStage = stage;
    }

    public void setPrimaryScene(Scene scene) {
        this.scene = scene;
    }

    public String buttonPressed(ActionEvent e) throws IOException, MessagingException {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if(source==yesButton){
            System.out.println("How to tell Mail.java that user clicked Yes?");
            return "POSITIVE";}
        else{subject.dlOrNot("no");
            System.out.println("How to tell Mail.java that user clicked No?");
            primaryStage.hide();
            return "NEGATIVE";}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of issues with the code you have posted, but let me just try to address the ones you ask about.

The reason the code hangs is that [`Application.launch(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.String...-)

> does not return until the application has exited

In general, you've kind of misunderstood the entire lifecycle of a JavaFX application here. You should think of the `start(...)` method as the equivalent of the `main(...)` method in a "traditional" Java application. The only thing to be aware of is that `start(...)` is executed on the FX Application Thread, so if you need to execute any blocking code, you need to put it in a background thread.

The `start(...)` method is passed a `Stage` instance for convenience, as the most common thing to do is to create a scene graph and display it in a stage. You are under no obligation to use this stage though, you can ignore it and just create your own stages as and when you need.

I think you can basically structure your code as follows (though, to be honest, I have quite a lot of trouble understanding what you're doing):

```
public class Mail extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage ignored) throws Exception {

        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);

        Message[] messages = /* retrieve messages */ ;
        for (Message message : messages) {
            if ( /* need to display window */) {
                showMessage(message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void showMessage(Message message) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("prompts.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();

        Controller controller = loader.getController();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 450, 250);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        stage.setTitle(...);

        // showAndWait will block execution until the window is hidden, so 
        // you can query which button was pressed afterwards:

        stage.showAndWait();

        if (controller.wasYesPressed()) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    // for IDEs that don't support directly launching a JavaFX Application:
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Obviously your logic for decided whether to show a window is more complex, but this will give you the basic structure.

To check which button was pressed, use `showAndWait` as above and then in your controller do

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private Button yesButton ;

    private boolean yesButtonPressed = false ;

    public boolean wasYesPressed() {
        return yesButtonPressed ;
    }

    // use different handlers for different buttons:
    @FXML
    private void yesButtonPressed() {
        yesButtonPressed = true ;
        closeWindow();
    }

    @FXML
    private void noButtonPressed() {
        yesButtonPressed = false ; // not really needed, but makes things clearer
        closeWindow();
    }

    private void closeWindow() {
        // can use any @FXML-injected node here:
        yesButton.getScene().getWindow().hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved!! James, thanks a lot! You provided just enough detail for me to fix the problems with my code, and answer my main question. I learned a lot from your post. Very much appreciated! Take care.

Comment: You are passing some arg in launch method how to receive that msg to display in wondow

Comment: @Bhushan https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters()