# JavaFX Application Remains in macOS Dock After Closure and Does Not Reopen Properly or Close

Tags: java, macos, javafx, trayicon

I'm developing a JavaFX application that needs to run in the background and send notifications to the user. To achieve this, I'm using FXTrayIcon for system tray integration and handling the application lifecycle to ensure it continues running in the background even when the main window is closed. However, I've encountered a couple of issues specific to macOS:

Persistent Dock Icon After Closure: Even after closing the application window, the application icon remains in the Dock. While the background process continues as expected (which is intended), I cannot quit the application from the Dock; it requires a force quit.

Reopening Issues: If the application is closed to the Dock (icon still visible) and I try to reopen it by clicking the Dock icon, no window appears, making it seem like the application is unresponsive.

Here's a simplified version of my code to illustrate how I'm setting up the application:

**HelloApplication.java: (main)**

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    this.primaryStage = stage;
    setupPrimaryStage();

    FXTrayIcon trayIcon = new FXTrayIcon(stage, getClass().getResource("/path/to/icon.png"));
    trayIcon.show();

    Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this::addAppToTray);
}

private void addAppToTray() {
       if (!Platform.isFxApplicationThread()) {
            Platform.runLater(this::addAppToTray);
            return;
        }

        if (primaryStage == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (primaryStage.isShowing()) {
            return;
        }
        primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to this [FXTrayIcon](https://github.com/dustinkredmond/FXTrayIcon) ?

Comment: @Abra Yes, that's true, but isn't the code that makes it work in the background actually the "setImplicitExit(false)" method? Do I have a missing configuration for macOs? (Note: any version of macOs has this problem.)

Comment: The threading code looks wrong. You are scheduling your`addAppToTray` method to run on the AWT event dispatch thread via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(…)` but then immediately resubmit it to the FX Application Thread using `Platform.runLater(…)`. That method doesn’t seem to do what its name suggests it should do; it just shows the window but doesn’t do anything with a tray icon. To completely exit, you would need to ensure both toolkits close down, but it’s not entirely clear what you’re trying to do here. I recommend creating and posting a [mre].

Comment: I don't use `FXTrayIcon`, but scanning the docs for it, it seems the entire point is that you should not have to mess with the AWT or Swing APIs at all, and should just be using the FX Application Thread for everything UI-related. It's not really clear what you're trying to do here that requires that library anyway: everything you have described can be done with the standard JavaFX API (though there may be some other requirements you haven't listed that make this library useful).

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24320562/2189127) is an example of an application that runs continuously in the background and shows a JavaFX window from time to time.

Comment: I found something like this; I think it's a very old bug and it persists;
https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8092032

Comment: The bug reported there is that (in some circumstances) using the "Quit" menu item from the *system menu* on Mac will not quit the application. That isn't what you seem to be reporting, unless I am mistaken. What you are reporting is that the dock icon remains visible when the window is closed. That is the expected behavior on a Mac. If the application (i.e. the JVM) is still running, the dock icon will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm developing a JavaFX application that needs to run in the background and send notifications to the user. To achieve this, I'm using FXTrayIcon ...

The [FXTrayIcon](https://github.com/dustinkredmond/FXTrayIcon) library isn't needed for this, and it's not what it really does other than as a side effect of managing a JavaFX application from a tray icon.

> ... I'm using FXTrayIcon for system tray integration ...

This is what FXTrayIcon does, but nothing else in your question suggests you need system tray integration.

> ... and handling the application lifecycle

This is done from the standard JavaFX API, mostly by overriding the `init()`, `start()`, and `stop()` methods in the `Application` class and by calling some utility methods in `Platform` (such as `setImplicitExit(...)`).

> Even after closing the application window, the application icon remains in the Dock.

This is the expected behavior, since your application is still running (you specifically say

> it continues running in the background even when the main window is closed.

The dock item represents a running application. Closing all the windows opened by an application doesn't necessarily mean that an application stops running. On my Mac, I have (for example) Microsoft Word installed. If I start Word and open a couple of windows, then close all the windows associated with the application, the icon remains in the dock and I can right click on it. I can still switch to the application (e.g. by using Command-Tab) and can access the menu, and open new windows. So again, because your application (the JVM) is still running, this is entirely expected.

The default behavior of JavaFX is for the *JavaFX platform* to exit when all windows are closed. This means the JavaFX Application Thread (and some other threads) will terminate and you can no longer display any JavaFX UI. This behavior can be turned off (as you do, and in fact as is also done for you by the FXTrayIcon library) by calling `Platform.setImplicitExit(false)`, in which case you must call `Platform.exit()` to exit the *JavaFX platform*.

When the JavaFX platform exits (either implicitly, or by calling `Platform.exit`), *if no non-daemon threads are running*, then the JVM will also exit. This is how the dock icon is usually removed from the dock when you close a JavaFX window (or all windows, if multiple are open).

The dock icon fails to be removed for two reasons in your example: first because you call `Platform.setImplicitExit(false)`, so the JavaFX Platform remains running, but also because the FXTrayIcon library relies on the AWT toolkit and starts the AWT event dispatch thread to manage the AWT tray icon behind the scenes. So even if you call `Platform.exit()`, the JVM will not exit because the AWT platform is still running.

---

I am not really convinced you need FXTrayIcon: it has basically nothing to do with the functionality you say you want. However, this is a quick overview of how it works.

AWT provides tray icon integration, but JavaFX does not. To use AWT tray icons in a JavaFX application would require managing multiple threads (the FX Application Thread and the AWT event dispatch thread), which is complex at best, as well as working with, for example, AWT menu items instead of JavaFX menu items. FXTrayIcon thus provides a JavaFX programmer's interface to the AWT tray icon, allowing the JavaFX programmer to work in a single thread and use familiar API such as JavaFX MenuItems, etc.

The typical use case for this is to place an icon in the *system tray* (which, of course, is completely different from the dock on Mac OSX). The user can pull up a menu from the tray icon, which typically does things like open or close the application window. Since a major use case involves having a non-JavaFX mechanism to manage the windows, FXTrayIcon turns off implicit exit for you, as long as one or more tray icons are displayed. There is also `showMessage(...)` type functionality, which shows notifications "close to" the tray icon. See the [Javadocs](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.dustinredmond.fxtrayicon/FXTrayIcon/latest/com.dustinredmond.fxtrayicon/com/dustinredmond/fxtrayicon/FXTrayIcon.html) for more details.

So the threading in the code in your post is completely unnecessary, since FXTrayIcon manages this for you, and completely wrong anyway. You use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` to call `addAppToTray()` on the AWT event dispatch thread. The first clause in `addAppToTray()` checks to see if you are on the JavaFX Application Thread: you are not, since you explicitly invoked the method on the AWT Event Dispatch Thread. So it then uses `Platform.runLater(...)` so send another invocation of `addAppToTray()` to the FX Application Thread.

When the FX Application Thread receives this second invocation, it first checks if `primaryStage` is null: it's not, because you necessarily initialized it earlier in `start()`, and then checks if the stage is not showing, and calls `show()` if it is not showing. Note this last check is redundant: `show()` is a no-op if the stage is already showing. Since `start()` is invoked on the FX Application Thread (read the docs), the entire method can be reduced to a single line (`primaryStage.show()`) if you omit the pointless `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` call.

Also note that `Platform.setImplicitExit(false)` is redundant, because FXTrayIcon is going to do that for you.

To exit the application entirely, you need to arrange for `Platform.exit()` to be called, and you need to remove any tray icons. If you hide all the tray icons, FXTrayIcon will restore the implicit exit status to its default, so closing all JavaFX windows after that will exit the platform.

Here is an example of using FXTrayIcon and exiting the entire application either via a button or via a menu item in the tray icon.

```
import com.dustinredmond.fxtrayicon.FXTrayIcon;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private FXTrayIcon trayIcon;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        this.primaryStage = stage;
        setupPrimaryStage();


        trayIcon = new FXTrayIcon(stage);

        MenuItem exitMenuItem = new MenuItem("Exit application");
        exitMenuItem.setOnAction(e -> exitCompletely());
        trayIcon.addMenuItem(exitMenuItem);

        trayIcon.addTitleItem(true);

        trayIcon.show();

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void exitCompletely() {
        trayIcon.hide();
        primaryStage.hide();
    }
    
    private void setupPrimaryStage() {
        Button exitButton = new Button("Exit Application");
        exitButton.setOnAction(e -> exitCompletely());
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(exitButton);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(40));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    }

}
```

Closing the window will not exit the application, but simply close the window. Using the Exit button, or the "Exit Application" menu item from the tray icon will exit the application completely. If you close the window, you can reopen it from the tray icon.

---

However, nothing in your question indicates you need any of this functionality. If all you want is a background thread running, which keeps running when all windows are closed, just call `Platform.setImplicitExit(false);`. Then just show and hide windows as needed, ensuring you do that on the FX Application Thread. A nice example of doing this is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24320562/2189127).

Comment: I apologize for the late reply. Thank you very much for your reply.  To make sure that the problem was with the "FXTrayIcon" or "setImplicitExit()" methods, I removed FXTrayIcon and all the code that makes it run in the background. I outputted dmg with JPackage and installed this dmg file on a macOs device and surprisingly the same problems persist.  The problem is not with the code, could it be a problem with jpackage? My jpackage command; https://codeshare.io/mpQx6X

Comment: @OzgurBaykal But what are the actual problems you say are persisting? Everything you have described seems to be the expected behavior on a Mac.

Comment: I know that it is expected behavior to appear in the dock because the JVM continues to run in the background. My problem is that when I press the program icon in the dock again, it does not open or when I right click on the application icon in the dock and say quit, nothing happens, I need to use the "Force Quit" option to quit. I know I can solve this quit issue by adding an exit MenuItem to the TrayIcon, but this is an afterthought for a user. Instead, he prefers to right-click on the icon in the Dock and say quit.

Comment: @OzgurBaykal AWT has a mechanism for detecting "App reopened events", which might work for this (just open the window you want to open in response to the event). Try `Desktop.getDesktop().addAppEventListener(new AppReopenedListener(e -> { /* open the window */});` (which I have not tested). The issue with quitting via the dock is that I think all that will do is close all windows, so either if you have `Platform.implicitExit` set to false, or if you are running non-daemon background threads, this will not cause the application to exit. This is the bug you referred to in another comment.